# Laravel data por extenso em portguês

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou utilizando Laravel 5.2 e gostaria de trazer as datas por extenso em português (pt_BR), porém o Carbon trás as datas textuais somente em inglês.

```
$post->created_at->formatLocalized('%B'); //"January"
```

No **config/app.php** o timezone está definido como 'America/Sao_Paulo' já no 'locale' testei 'pt_BR', 'pt' e 'pt_BR.UTF-8', e não consegui trazer em português.

Tive sucesso no Tinker, ao utilizar o setlocate:

```
>>> setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8');
>>> $post = Post::find(1);
>>> $post->created_at->formatLocalized('%B');
=> "janeiro"
```

Vale ressaltar que tenho o pacote de linguagem no servidor (Ubuntu Trusty x64):

```
$ locale -a

POSIX
C.UTF-8
C
en_**.UTF-8
pt_BR.utf8
pt_PT.utf8
```

Minha principal dúvida é qual a melhor forma de trazer as datas do Carbon por extenso e em pt_BR? Onde posso colocar no código o setlocale? Ou seria melhorar utilizar o Localization?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057450/whats-the-best-way-to-localise-a-date-on-laravel

Comment: O Carbon é baseado em DateTime logo não é afetada pelo locale.

Comment: Obrigado @daniel, irei utilizar a classe Date conforme atualizei na pergunta.

Comment: @rray não é bem assim, hein. Existe uma implementação de `strftime` dentro do `Carbon`. O método que você pode usar para isso é o `Carbon::formatLocalized`. rsrsrss

Comment: É específico para o framework Laravel. Por isso não considero duplicada.

Comment: Removida resposta do corpo da pergunta e consequente adição da mesma ao campo de respostas.

Answer (score 1):

A partir da versão do carbon 2.30.0, você pode utilizar a função `translatedFormat`

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2021-12-08 11:35')->locale('pt-BR');
echo $date->translatedFormat('d F Y'); //  16 março 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Conteúdo: erroneamente adicionado pelo autor da pergunta ao corpo da pergunta**

Realmente o Carbon não suporta locales, porque utiliza a classe DateTime:

> Unfortunately the base class DateTime does not have any localization support. To begin localization support a formatLocalized($format) method has been added. The implementation makes a call to strftime using the current instance timestamp. If you first set the current locale with setlocale() then the string returned will be formatted in the correct locale.

Como o próprio site do package recomenda:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');                     
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Donnerstag 25 Dezember 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, '');                           
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Thursday 25 December 1975
```

Achei aqui uma [boa opção](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057450/whats-the-best-way-to-localise-a-date-on-laravel#answer-25939511) para resolver o problema, utilizando o [laravel-date](https://github.com/jenssegers/date) que estende o Carbon e oferece multiple languages.